# How to optimise fetching data on nested objects in javascript

Tags: javascript

My response json would look something like this

```
const products = [{  
    "brand": "xyz",
    "category": "T-shirt",
    "attributes": [
        {
             "name": "color",
             "attribute_values": [
                 {
                     "value": "blue"
                 },
                 {
                     "value": "green"
                 }
              ]
        },
        {
            "name": "size",
            "attribute_values": [
                {
                     "value": "18"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}, {...}]
```

I want to flatten the nested object and get unique values for each of keys i.e

```
brands = ['xyz', ...] 
category = ['t-shirts', 'footwear', ...] 
attributes = [{'color':['green', 'blue', ...]}, {'size':[...]}, ...]
```

I tried the following code but this results in multiple loops. Can i optimise it ?

```
products.map((product) => {
    product.attributes.map((p) => {
        p.attribute_values.map(i => {
           return console.log(i.value)
        }) 
    }) 
})
```

Comment: The flattened data structure you want to convert it to is not valid js. For the last array you have a key-value pair which does not make sense. It should be wrapped in `{}` if it is an object

Comment: forgot to add it here in question. edited it

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this it will help you

```
const updateValue =(key,value,ar)=>{
  var newVal=[];
  if(ar[key]){
    newVal = ar[key];
    newVal= Array.isArray(value)? [...newVal,...value] : [...newVal,value]
  }else{
    newVal= Array.isArray(value)? [...value] : [value]
  }
  return newVal;
} 

let obj = products.reduce((acc, k) => {
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(k)) {
      acc = {...acc,
            [key] : updateValue(key,value,acc)
           }
  }
  return acc;
  }, {});
console.log(obj);
```

You can access your keys from this object